# How do I prevent JSX code from turning into a mess in vs code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I tried to output simple JSX to check whether my bootstrap is working or not. But vs code turns it into a mess.

here's a picture of the code before saving it https://prnt.sc/p5zs9c

Picture of messy code after saving it https://prnt.sc/p5zt25

It gives messy format to the code.

I am using Prettier and my settings.json file includes following:

```
{
  "window.zoomLevel": 0,
  "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/php/php.exe",
  "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "expanded",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "/css"
    }
  ],
  "prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": true
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to setup the JSX support. Also I'd recommend using prettier for code formatting: https://github.com/prettier/prettier

Comment: check the formatter you are using.

Comment: I am using prettier. How do I configure it for JSX?